# Jquery Mobile conflict with other javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

i am working on my mobile site 
   there is a jquerymobile script, is conflict with other libraries.

```
  <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/js/all.js"></script>  
<script src="/js/jquery.dainer.js"></script>
<script src="/js/commoncripts.js"></script> 
<script src="/js/cart.js"></script> 
<script src="/ui/jquery.js"></script>  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    objl10n = <#tag:js_translated_messages /#> ;
</script>
```

all function working without this script. 
  here is my site : http://bit.ly/1ETOzRf ...

please guide me,

Comment: You are using (/*! jQuery v1.7.1) you need to use 1.11 (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js). also you need to check the console on your browser, and check each error. You can see them all of them here --- http://s21.postimg.org/pkl87xcpj/Capture.png

Comment: this works on home page. but not here http://bit.ly/1A6OTcq

Comment: when you search for a domain

Comment: looks ok now, i presume you fixed it. always have the browser console open to spot errors and warnings

Comment: not fixed yet bit.ly/1A6OTcq, i m working on style, after removing jquerymobile for a while

Answer (score 1):

You can't use jquery mobile and jquery UI without using [noConflict](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode. Even doing so they don't play well with each other, you will always have some class conflicts etc.

You shouldn't use jquery ui, jquery and jquery mobile all on same page, do you really need them all?

Learn more from here: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Comment: thanks for reply, there are javascipt which hosted on other server, cant edit, i am not smart with javascipt, please guide

Comment: If javascript is hosted on other server you don't have access to, how do you expect to solve this problem?!